# Robot Framework change table cell value with Press Key

Tags: python, xpath, robotframework

I'm trying to make a robot test where I input a value into a table cell and then hits enter to update the table.

I tried first with Input Text, but it doesn't work with table cells since they are not text fields:

```
Input Value To Cell
  |  [Arguments]   ${row}    ${col}    ${amount}
  |  Double Click Element   xpath=//*/table/tbody/tr[${row}]/td[${col}]
  |  Input Text   xpath=//*/table/tbody/tr[${row}]/td[${col}]   ${amount}
```

This results with:

InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.

---

I think my only option is to use Press Key and provide it with the cell location. So, this is what I've tried:

```
Input Value To Cell
  | [Arguments]   ${row}    ${col}    ${amount}
  | ${cell}   Get Table Cell    xpath=//*   ${row}    ${col}
  | Press Key   ${cell}   ${amount}
```

This results with: Cell in table xpath=//* in row #x and column #y could not be found. I've tried checking already set cell values with Table Should Contain and it finds a table with that?

---

Double Click works just fine, it makes the cell 'editable', so I'm just looking for a way to write something. I couldn't find any keywords to just write or press keys (something like Press Key but without the locator, just pressing buttons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself. I did not realize the DOM was dynamic, so after going bashing my head to a wall for a while, I decided to check if the DOM changes when I double click the cell.

And Boom, an input element appeared, and now I could xpath the input field with its class and use Input Text keyword :).